# How to select passengers that never flew to a city

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will send the Database Description in an Image.

I tried this Select but I'm afraid that this isn't right

```
   SELECT t.type , a.ICAOId , a.name , ci.id , c.ISOAlpha2ID , p.docReference , ti.docReference , ti.number , p.name , p.surname
FROM dbo.AirportType t 
INNER JOIN dbo.Airport a ON t.type = a.type
INNER JOIN dbo.City ci ON a.city = ci.id
INNER JOIN dbo.Country c ON ci.ISOalpha2Id = c.ISOalpha2Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Passenger p ON c.ISOalpha2Id = p.nationality
INNER JOIN dbo.Ticket ti ON p.docReference = ti.docReference
WHERE NOT ci.id = 'Tokyo'
```

Can you please help to get this right?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJxrg.png)

Comment: Skip the image, most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you'er using MySQL and not MS SQL Server?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow Gp! It would be very helpful if you could spare time to get a [tour] and learn [ask] - don't forget to write [mcve] for your question. you should narrow down the tables and please post DDL instead of a picture.

Comment: by the way, why didn't you take the route of `Passanger` -> `BoardingPass` -> `Flight` -> `Airport` -> `City`? do tickets guarantee if they have checked in (or flown to)? or perhaps i'm missing some domain knowledge here..

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of the passengers that HAVE flown to the city then use that as a subquery to select the ones not in the list

I am just going to make an example of how it should be done

Subquery:

```
SELECT p.id FROM passengers
JOIN tickets t ON p.id = t.passengerID
JOIN city c ON c.id = t.cityID
```

Now you just put that into another query that selects the elements not in it

```
SELECT * FROM passenger
WHERE id not in ( 
SELECT p.id FROM passengers
JOIN tickets t ON p.id = t.passengerID
JOIN city c ON c.id = t.cityID
WHERE c.name= 'tokyo'
)
```

Notice I didn't use your attribute names, you will have to change those.

This was a bit simplified version of what you will have to do because the city is not directly in your tickets table. So you will also have to join tickets, with coupons, and flights to get the people that have flown to a city. But from there it is the same.

Overall I believe this should help you get what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example is not provided.

Here is a conceptual example, that could be easily extended to a real scenario.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @passenger TABLE (passengerID INT PRIMARY KEY, passenger_name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @passenger (passengerID, passenger_name) VALUES
(1, 'Anna'),
(2, 'Paul');

DECLARE @city TABLE (cityID INT PRIMARY KEY, city_name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @city (cityID, city_name) VALUES
(1, 'Miami'),
(2, 'Orldando'),
(3, 'Tokyo');

-- Already visited cities
DECLARE @passenger_city TABLE (passengerID INT, cityID INT);
INSERT @passenger_city (passengerID, cityID) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 3);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * FROM @passenger;
SELECT * FROM @city;
SELECT * FROM @passenger_city;

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.passengerID, b.cityID 
    FROM @passenger AS c
        CROSS JOIN @city AS b   -- get all possible combinations of passengers and cities
    EXCEPT  -- filter out already visited cities
    SELECT passengerID, cityID FROM @passenger_city
)
SELECT c.*, b.city_name
FROM rs
    INNER JOIN @passenger AS c ON c.passengerID = rs.passengerID
    INNER JOIN @city AS b ON b.cityID = rs.cityID
ORDER BY c.passenger_name, b.city_name;
```

**Output**

| passengerID | passenger_name | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna | Orldando |
| 1 | Anna | Tokyo |
| 2 | Paul | Miami |
| 2 | Paul | Orldando |